# setting the height of an image within a flex-wrap element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

If I create a 2x2 grid of divs using flex box wrap, then place an image in each div:-

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="item"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x500"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x500"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x500"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x500"></div>
</div>

#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: burlywood;
}
.item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 50%;
  background-colour: bisque;
}
```

If the image's native height is deeper than the flex item it will push my content deeper than the 100vh I set my wrapper to.

I want each image to fill the height of its flex item div, in this example 50% of the screen height, and for the image width to be in the correct ratio.

I've tried setting the image height to 100% of its container but I can't get it to work. (unless the image native height is shorter, then it will expand to fit).

It also works if I explicitly set the height of the flex item divs to 33.333% but that doesn't seem like the right solution to me.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid a solution which involves setting the height of the .item divs, although it works in this simple example it causes me further problems with the rest of my layout

Comment: What about a max-height instead of a height on them? would that upset the layout?

Comment: I was setting some elements with fixed px sizes and just filling the rest of the empty space by setting one element to flex-grow, if I have to give that element a size or even I think a max size it won't work, I think I need to go back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to set the `.item` height to 50%, and the give `.item img` a maximum height, like this:

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: burlywood;
}
.item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: bisque;
  height: 50%;
}
.item > img {
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="item"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x500"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x500"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x500"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x500"></div>
</div>
```

Here's [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3yaexkdr/1/) if that's your preference.

Comment: And here's [another fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3yaexkdr/2/) that will show the outlines - just because it's easier to see where it works this way... :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your image's height only to make it keep the correct ratio. Add the following class to your CSS to apply height of `50vh` and I think your problem will be resolved if I understood it correctly.

```
.item img {
  height:50vh;
}
```

You can play around with the adjustments to get what you need after that.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @trevorp for the correct formating of my answer.